# Is there any way to generate solutions to a linear system given the domain of the terms (and some binomial products)?

Tags: number-theory, binomial-coefficients

Consider

$2l + 3m +4n =11$

I have constraint

$$ 0 \leq l \leq 4$$

$$ 0 \leq m \leq 4$$

and,

$ 0  \leq n \leq 4$

Given this constraint would there be any systematic way to write do all the triple (l,m,n)

Which solve this equation?

Now, after that , would there be a closed from for this summation

$$\sum_{2l + 3m +4n =11} \binom{4}{l} \cdot \binom{7}{m} \cdot \binom{12}{n}$$

My work:

We can immediately figure out true bounds are

$$ 0 \leq m \leq 3 $$
$$ 0 \leq n \leq 2$$
since if they go any higher than that, the sum would overshoot eleven

Comment: Are $m,n,$ and $l$ integers or this isn't a number theory question?

Comment: A "closed form" of the summation is $[x^{11}](1+x^2)^4(1+x^3)^7(1+x^4)^{12}$.

Comment: they are all integers